# Can I use google code prettify for commercial use?

Tags: google-code-prettify

Can I use google code prettify for commercial use. I see that Code license - Apache License 2.0. Do I need to have a copy of the Apache license?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Code Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is published under Apache License 2.0. Take a look to this [FAQ](http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html). It allows you to **use Apache software in packages or distributions that you create.**

However you need to **include a copy of license in any distribution of your software** and **show clear attribution to Google**.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Code Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is distributed under [Apache Licence 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

This means that you are free to use it in a commercial application provided that you also include a copy of the Apache License with your application.

**RELATED:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/1007376/2081889

Comment: I do not understands this "include a copy of the Apache License".

Comment: @user3008628 You simply have to include the [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) somewhere in your application where it can be found by the user. If you distribute binaries, then as a text file with your distributed package. If you present a GUI, then in some "about" or "licenses" section _and_ as a text file.